# PDOException after installing php 7

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, wamp

I used wamp 2.5 with php 5.6
I decided to go to Php 7.0.10

So I uninstalled wamp 2.5 and installed Wampserver 3.0.6 64 bit x64
**(Apache 2.4.23 - PHP 7.0.10 - MySQL 5.7.14 - PhpMyAdmin 4.6.4 - Adminer 4.2.5 - PhpSysInfo 3.2.5)**

I had no errors during install / uninstall

I then created the same database and imported the database, Then I transferred my files

**But when I want to go on my website I have this error**

```
( ! ) Fatal error: in C:\wamp\www\mysite\config\pdo.php on line 12
( ! ) PDOException: in C:\wamp\www\mysite\config\pdo.php on line 12
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0027  370576  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0030  377872  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\mysite\layouts\header.php' ) ...\index.php:3
3   0.0044  383096  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\mysite\config\config.php' )  ...\header.php:2
4   0.0046  386000  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\mysite\config\pdo.php' ) ...\config.php:2
5   0.0046  386584  __construct ( ) ...\pdo.php:12
```

Here are my files :

**Index.php**

```
<?php
$title = 'Accueil';
require_once __DIR__.'/layouts/header.php';
?>
....
```

**Header.php**

```
<?php session_start (); 
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/config/config.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
...
```

**Config.php**

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite/config/pdo.php';
...
```

**Pdo.php**

```
<?php 
try 
{
  $engine = 'mysql';
  $host ='localhost';
  $port = '';
  $database = 'mysite';
  $user = 'root';
  $password = '';
  $dns = $engine.':port='.$port.';dbname='.$database.";host=".$host;

  $bdd = new PDO($dns, $user, $password);
}

catch (Exeption $erreur)
{
  die ('Erreur : '.$erreur->getMessage());
}
?>
```

How to solve this problem ? 
Thank you

Comment: If it's a fatal, there should be a error message. What is it?

Comment: Very weird i have copied and modified the variables and everything is working.

Comment: From the error `pdo.php` has a constructor. Please show the real code as summaries only cause confusion

Comment: _Small Note:_ WAMPServer current version is 3.0.9 (3.0.10 coming soon). You can upgrade 3.0.6 to 3.0.9 easily, it will only change WAMPServer code not versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP and you can get it from [the backup repo, its easier to navigate than SourceForge](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) You will also find lots of ADDONs for additional versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP/MariaDB there as well

Comment: Thank you, I reinstalled wamp and it works
I think it came from the configuration of my ports